# Reading a a text file into a structure and splitting it

Tags: c, eclipse

My program hangs when the fscanf function is called. I have no idea why. I am trying to read information from the following text file:

```
     R1 N001 N003 20
     R2 N002 N001 5
     R3 N001 0 10
     R4 N002 N003 10
     R5 N003 N000 5
     I1 0 N002 10
```

Here's my structure:

```
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #ifndef MYDATA_H_
    #define MYDATA_H_

    typedef struct comp{
       char *name;
       char *node1;
       char *node2;
       float val;
    } ComponentType;

    typedef struct ListNodeT{
       ComponentType Component;
       float currnet;
       float voltage;
       float power;
    } ListNodeType;

    #endif
```

This is my function to read the textfile and populate my structure of ComponentType.

```
void ReadFile (ComponentType *CircuitData, int *numEl, int *numNodes){
*numEl = 0;
*numNodes = 0;
int index= 0;
FILE *myFile = fopen("mydata.dat", "r");


if (myFile == NULL){
    printf("Error: File the file is not open");
}
printf("This worked\n"); //gets to this point

while (!feof(myFile)){
fscanf(myFile,"%cf",CircuitData[index].name,
    CircuitData[index].node1,CircuitData[index].node2,
    &CircuitData[index].val);
printf("\nfscanf works");
*CircuitData[index].node1 = intFromString(CircuitData[index].node1);
*CircuitData[index].node2 = intFromString(CircuitData[index].node2);


    if ((int)CircuitData[index].node1 > *numNodes ){
        *numNodes = (int)CircuitData[index].node1;
    }

    if ( (int)CircuitData[index].node2 > *numNodes ){
        *numNodes = (int)CircuitData[index].node2;
    }

    (*numEl)+=1;
    index++;
}
fclose(myFile);
```

Comment: Have you initialized your CircuitData array?

Answer (score 2):

You have many errors in your code.

Lets start with the `fscanf` call: You only have the format `"%c"` which reads a single character, but you have many values you want to parse. You need one format code for each variable, and the need to be correct (i.e. `"%s"` for strings):

```
fscanf(myFile, " %s %s %s %f",
    CircuitData[index].name,
    CircuitData[index].node1,
    CircuitData[index].node2,
    &CircuitData[index].val);
```

Note the leading space, which tells `fscanf` to skip leading whitespace in the input, which is needed because the newline will still be in the input buffer from the line before.

Then lets continue with what may cause the above code to crash: You must allocate memory for the strings! Either allocate dynamically (e.g. `CircuitData[index].name = malloc(SOME_SIZE)`) or declare them as array (e.g. `char name[SOME_SIZE]`).

And as you use the `node1` and `node2` fields, these should really be integer filed (e.g. `int node1`). Then you need a couple of temporary variables for the string you read with `fscanf`. And there are functions in the standard library to convert strings to integers, like [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol):

```
CircuitData[index].node1 = strtol(temp_node1, NULL, 10);
```

You also have a problem with your reading loop, and should to e.g.

```
while (fscanf(...) == 4) { ... }
```

And of course, I assume you have allocated memory for the `CircuitData` array?

You do have lots of other pointer related errors right now, but if you change `node1` and `node2` to become integers, some of those will be solved.